# What are the benefits of social widgets on e-commerce sites?

Tags: e-commerce, social-media

I am making design of e-commerce site and one of specifications was that there needs to be
facebook and twitter widgets in site. So my question is  "Is there any reason to use twitter and facebook widgets in e-commerce site ?"

Comment: You can use social media on product description to show your audience that you like/want that object. You can use after check out to display your audience "xxxx just bought zzzz on yyy.com"

Comment: Shouldn't you be asking the person who wrote the specification as to why they included it? There should have been a reason why they included it in the first place - request from users / business drivers...

Answer (score 2):

On-site social media modules can help retailers drive sales conversion and increase revenues. Here are a a couple of examples:

1) Plum District is getting 35% sales conversion rate using social media on their site ([link](http://blog.shopsocially.com/2013/11/14/shopsocially-webinar-unravels-how-plum-district-is-getting-35-sales-conversion-rate-using-social-media/))

2) Carol's Daughter is getting 8% revenue uplift using social media on their site ([link](http://blog.shopsocially.com/2013/10/10/shopsocially-webinar-reveals-how-carols-daughter-is-generating-8-revenue-uplift-via-social-media/))

Answer (score 1):

A reason to include social media widgets on an e-commerce site would be to highlight promotions or campaigns. For example, including a [Twitter widget related to certain hashtag](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/embedded-timelines), and you could show the buzz people are generating regarding your promotions/campaigns based on the hashtag popularity, or perhaps just tweets that get sent to your twitter account.

Could also be bad publicity, if a campaign gets negative feedback, but the transparency could earn trust from customers.

I believe it improves the user's connection/involvement with the e-commerce site, and engages them more with hopefully up-to-date commentary and information, hence their experience is enhanced by including the social media widgets.

In terms of design, or look and feel, fitting in with the e-commerce's design, that may be challenging. Not sure if it is possible. But most users that will gain from it will already be comfortable with the social media's look and feel, so I believe it would at least be a good trial.

Comment: Guy asked about the need of Widgets, not about the need of promotions in social media as a whole. Widgets are clumsy and they have design, that most of time, is not responsive, and not customizable. That is why, there should be the reason behind use in web page.

Comment: @Deele I didn't address promotions in social media, I mentioned a suggestion as to why you would want to include a widget on an e-commerce site. Guess I should re-word it.